# how to get url value after question mark in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get the url value after a question mark in javascript?

I want the following behaviour:

```
if value is yes then 10+2 
else if value is no then 10.
```

I want to output with alert messages.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 text-center width100">
    <a href="piccal.html" class="btn btn-success" id="yes">PIC Grant Calculator</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 text-center width100">
    <a href="piccal.html" class="btn btn-danger" id="no">PIC Grant Calculator</a>
</div>

<script> 
if (value == no) {
    alert('hello');
}
</script>

<script> 
if (value == yes) {
    alert('hi');
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use this code:

```
var a = location.href; 
var b = a.substring(a.indexOf("?")+1);
```

Answer (score 12):

use javsacript and type:

```
location.search
```

Comment: use `window.location.search` as a variable and it will return you the full string of what is in the URL to the right of the "?" and including it, you may also push data to this location using this method. Andrew's answer is correct